# why am i getting the attribute error?

Tags: python

The aim of my code is for the user to enter the sentence, ask for a position and then the whole thing to be read to one/two files, ie the positions and the words.

```
sentencelist=[] #variable list for the sentences
word=[] #variable list for the words
positionofword=[]
words= open("words.txt","w")
position= open("position.txt","w")
question=input("Do you want to enter a sentence? Answers are Y or N.").upper()
if question=="Y":
    sentence=input("Please enter a sentance").upper() #sets to uppercase so it's easier to read
    sentencetext=sentence.isalpha or sentence.isspace()
    while sentencetext==False: #if letters have not been entered
        print("Only letters are allowed") #error message
        sentence=input("Please enter a sentence").upper() #asks the question again
        sentencetext=sentence.isalpha #checks if letters have been entered this time

elif question=="N":
    print("The program will now close")

else:
    print("please enter a letter")


sentence_word = sentence.split(' ')
for (i, check) in enumerate(word): #orders the words
    print(sentence)

sentence_words = sentence.split(' ')
word = input("What word are you looking for?").upper() #asks what word they want
for (i, check) in enumerate(sentence_words): #orders the words
    if (check == word):
        positionofword=print(str(("your word is in this position:", i+1)))
        positionofword=i+1
        break
else:
    print("This didn't work")

words.write(word + " ")
position.write(positionofword + " ")

words.close()
position.close()
```

That's my code, however I am getting this error

```
position.write(positionofword + " ")
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Bear in mind that the word file is empty as well.

Comment: in your for loop you're reassigning `positionofword` to i+1, which makes it an integer. You cant use the `+` operator on an int and a string

Comment: Simon so do i take out the 'postionofword=i+1'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code fails at `position.write(positionofword + " ")`, as `positionofword` is an integer and `" "` is a string, and python does not support adding integers to strings directly.

Use `str()` to convert `positionofword` to string:

```
position.write(str(positionofword) + " ")
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is that the interpreter of python is reading the type of the interger first and then the `+ " "` part. This produces an error as the interpreter is trying to use the integer add function which does not support the addition of a string.

You have to specifically tell the python interpreter that you want to use the string addition (concatenation) function.

```
position.write(str(positionofword) + " ")
```

Comment: thank you so much. this has had me stumped for such a long time.